# Ruby on Rails - link_to - Generate Urls with "-" (hyphens) instead of "_" (underscores)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I've seen a few similar questions but none that address this issue specifically.

I'm looking to get SEO Urls. I don't feel a need to put slugs in my database, just seems unnecessary, just want to use dashes in the URL instead of underscores. I figure for incoming requests I just use a rewrite rule on the web server level so anything passed to rails would be converted.

However links across my site would still have underscores instead of dashes. How would I go about modifying the "link_to" method so that it generated URLs with hyphens instead of underscores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your routes file to map the controllers with underscores as dashes like

```
resources "gokart-races", :as => :gokart_races, :controller => :gokart_races
```

This will map all urls to look something like

```
http://myurl.com/gokart-races/new
http://myurl.com/gokart-races/35
```

etc

Comment: HOLY CRAP. That worked. It's like black magic voodoo. So rails actually checks the routes files before outputting a link! I need to research how this works.... Thank you for this. My mind has been blown.